# How to save text in Photoshop and open it in Illustrator without pixellation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, cs6

I want to do silkscreen printing. I have done all the labels with Photoshop and saved as PDF. But, my printer said it is very blurry.

I need to use Illustrator. So, if I have already done my label with Photoshop, how can I export my file to illustrator and make all my texts unpixalated?

Should I type everything in Illustrator instead? How can I send to Photoshop with vector base (not bitmap)?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can convert your Photoshop text layers to Illustrator (vectors).**

Simply save your Photoshop file with the text layers in .psd, and open it in Illustrator.

[You can see the how-to guide on this url on Stack Exchange.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55345/how-to-keep-the-text-in-vector-in-photoshop-without-rasterizing-it-or-flattening)

Once you're done, you can simply reasave your new file into PDF or EPS or AI.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just text based, use illustrator.

You must of rasterized your text in Photoshop, hence the blurring.

I suggest sticking to Illustrator if all of your work is going to be vector and doesn't need any finalizing in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how best to import vectorised text from Illustrator in to Photoshop, My advice would be to first outline the text in Illustrator, Expand the vectors, and personally I would highlight the text, copy and paste into a Photoshop layer as a shape layer, **However** bear in mind that this **will not be editable** in any way outside of changing the colour and adding blending effects.

I agree with SaturnsEye before me, Do the artwork and text in Illustrator if you can, if there are any rasterised elements output them from Photoshop at high resolution and drop them into Illustrator, rather than going the other way around.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your text is not sharp is because you have converted it from the original text (vector based graphic) into a picture (raster based image).

The first thing you can try is to open your Photoshop image into Illustrator and select Object > Image Trace > Make

Expand the result and your text is converted into a vector format. If this doesn't produce adequate results for your needs it will need to be entirely rebuilt in Illustrator.

You can save your document as a PDF within Illustrator without having to convert it back in Photoshop, but there are many ways to bring images from Illustrator into Photoshop without converting them to a bitmap.

Comment: Hello Melissa, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Illustrator 10 you have to convert in Photoshop your text layers into Shapes (right click in Layers Window), then save file as .psd and then open it in Illustrator with "Convert Layers to Objects" option.

Answer (score 0):

Save the text from Photoshop as an .eps file. You should then be able to open it in Illustrator as a vector graphic. Worked great !!

Answer (score 0):

To use it is screen printing you have to set the text Anti-alias to **none**.
Also the minimum depth to 300ppi.

See the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Save a copy of your psd, with only the type layers, deleting all other layers. Do not flatten, keep layers. Now in Illustrator go file/place and select your psd.There will be options that pop up now. Select the "Convert Layers To Objects" button. This will place the type as editable live vector type.

Answer (score -2):

Save the text from Photoshop as an .eps file. You should then be able to open it in Illustrator as a vector graphic. It works the other way around too.